# save sqlsuite error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to save my sql file in sqlsuite, but the error occured.
[image]

Please let me know if you know something.

Comment: What does the error mean in English?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, this issue happened because I installed the sqlsuite for 64 bit version and it is not compatible. The issue is resolved when I unistall and install the 32 bit version